# in c# website how we can connect two users so that they can pass textbox values to each other?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on c# website that is basically a type of game with multiple images. It's multiplayer game, 2 people should be involved in this. How can I connect these two people so that action performed by one user is visible to other. Means if one user adds some thing in textbox it should be visible to other user.
Can someone help me with this please.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), it's an awesome tool for bidirectional communication between a server and its clients.
A easy tutorial for it can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr